# writting scala object to json file through jackson API

Tags: scala

I'm getting the output {} like this only. I am not understanding why I am not getting the correct output

I have tried upto with the all API's of JSON to convert my  scala object to JSON but I am failed.

```
package com.sathya
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.{ObjectMapper, SerializationConfig}
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig

case class Employee(empNo:Int,empName:String,salary:Int)

class NewClass{
  val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)

  def convertJavaToJason(obj:Employee):String={
      var output:String=mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    return output;
  }
}
object JSONObjectClass1{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var emp=new Employee(101,"Piyush",1000);
    var nc=new NewClass();
    var zp:String=nc.convertJavaToJason(emp);
    println(zp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I strongly recommend to switch `com.fasterxml.jackson`.

org.codehaus.jackson is an older version of Jackson, while com.fasterxml.jackson represents the new project and package.

The reason is, Jackson has moved from Codehaus to Github when releasing Jackson 2.

You need to use:
`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.9",
 "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.9"
)`

and change your code to (maybe more imports should be added):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

case class Employee(empNo:Int,empName:String,salary:Int)

class NewClass {
  val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  def convertJavaToJason(obj:Employee):String = {
    val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    objectMapper.writeValue(out, obj)
    out.toString
}

object JSONObjectClass1{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val emp=new Employee(101,"Piyush",1000);
    val nc = new NewClass();
    val zp:String = nc.convertJavaToJason(emp);
    println(zp);
  }
}
```

A more easier way is to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

Add the dependencies:
`libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.5"`

And your code will be like:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson

case class Employee(empNo:Int,empName:String,salary:Int)

class NewClass {
  val gson = new Gson()

  def convertJavaToJason(obj:Employee):String = {
    gson.toJson(obj)
}

object JSONObjectClass1{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val emp=new Employee(101,"Piyush",1000);
    val nc = new NewClass();
    val zp:String = nc.convertJavaToJason(emp);
    println(zp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Error:(10, 46) not found: type ScalaObjectMapper
  val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper

Comment: Error:(11, 31) not found: value DefaultScalaModule
  objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

Comment: I added the relevant imports to my answer above - `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper`